# Checkout and customer registration fails when customer is registering during checkout

Tags: php, magento

I'm having a problem with my Magento storefront where customers who register with my store during checkout cannot complete the OnePageCheckout checkout process. This error is rare and hard for me to reproduce. Here are the error messages I get:

> Payment Transaction Failed Reminder
> Payment transaction failed. Reason: Customer email is required.
>
> Payment Transaction Failed Reminder
> Payment transaction failed. Reason: This customer email already exists.

I'm pretty sure that this means the customer tried a second time, and couldn't complete the second checkout either.

This error is strange to me for two reasons. First of all, that error should never happen at this point in checkout; since the validation on the one page checkout does not allow you to register with an email address that already exists, the second kind of error should be impossible. The validation checks also won't let you go any further without entering an email address at all (the first kind of error). In both cases the final payment tab, which seems to be where the error is encountered, should be hidden via JavaScript.

How is it possible that a customer gets all the way to the point where they can click the Place Order button, but didn't get screened by the validation on the registration tab?

My guess is that it could be a browser that causes the validation to not work, and lets the customer get all the way to the last bit.

When I say this error is "rare," I mean that it happens with something like 2 out of 1000 orders.

I am pretty sure it happens when the Quote gets converted to an Order. On the Order Save event, it will try and save the customer, as part of the transaction, while also processing the payment. I don't think the payment gateway is throwing the error, but maybe control was passed on to that class. It most likely happens just after the `saveOrderAction()` function is called in the `OnePageController.php` file. After an error gets thrown in this function, the error gets reported like this in the stack trace:

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->sendPaymentFailedEmail($this->getOnepage()->getQuote(), $e->getMessage());
```

This is where the "Payment Transaction Failed Reminder" email gets generated. I think that the error has to be in this part:

```
$this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();
```

How can I go about finding where in the PHP code this error occurs? How can I correct this so that I don't lose customers who're in the process of trying to purchase from me?

My storefront is running on Magento version 1.9.1.1.

**Update:** Just got another one of these. The customer record is completely missing, but there is a shipping and billing address. Very strange.

Comment: Have you setup any tests to try to replicate the data? If not, I'd suggest getting some going with Selenium asap.

Comment: I can replicate it using Ecomdev testing suite. But that is not a full on browsing test. I have a funny suspicion that the customer record gets deleted on a Roll-back, because something went wrong, but only the Customer data is missing, and not the Addresses, and they actually have a customer ID assigned.

Comment: I have done allot of browser testing, with about 100 different scenarios, and different characters, but the web pages stops any invalid entries before you can even place the order.

Comment: please contact OneStepCheckout support for this and mention your OneStepCheckout version used as well. Latest s 4.0.4

Comment: We are not using OneStepCheckout.

Comment: This smells like a race condition. Have you got a MySQL Master/Slave setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need more Info, but my bet is this is a MySQL master/slave race condition. Had that happening before once.
The solution was to use https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy which is Lua scriptable.
The load balancing between master and slave (beyond just read/write splitting) was better, and the issue could be solved with a small Lua script.

Comment: We have a Master/slave setup, but only for fail over, and not load balancing. Thanks for the tip anyway. Almost thought this was the problem.

Comment: Hey @ShaunOReilly I take it that you ended up confirming that this was due to master/slave replication?  I'm hitting this same issue with a different checkout extension.  I noticed that it seems to affect only Safari users though, so I was really expecting this to be a client-side issue where the existing email address wasn't properly validated.  I'm pretty sure I don't even have master/slave replication setup at all but looking into that.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Firecheckout's Onepage Extension, but it sounds like the same issue we are having.

Every now and then we will have a customer record go missing, on the Order View screen we will only see

Customer Name **Guest**

Email *nothing*

I believe this occurs when a customer enters an invalid email address. Check your exception.log, if this occurs for us we see the following:

```
2012-02-01T23:47:30+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in     /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(409): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(79): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('sales_email_ord...', 'general', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1310): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/local/TM/FireCheckout/Model/Type/Standard.php(1079): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/local/TM/FireCheckout/controllers/IndexController.php(559): TM_FireCheckout_Model_Type_Standard->saveOrder()
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): TM_FireCheckout_IndexController->saveOrderAction()
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /var/www/html/index.php(106): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

Comment: Sound like an extremely good answer - I am going to check this out!

Comment: The more I work with Magento, the more I wince at its internals. Throwing a stack-trace exception when a customer enters an invalid email address is ... let's be polite and say "indicative of shoddy work." RFCs 5321 & 5322 have been around for decades!